# 2 List Comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried to write this, where s is just an int

```
 for box in current_boxes:
        for i in range(len(box)):
            box[i] = box[i]*s
        all_boxes.append(box)
```

as a list comprehension. But my result is not the same. That's what I've tried.

```
all_boxes = [all_boxes.append(box[i]*s) for box in current_boxes for i in range(len(box))]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you want `all_boxes` to be a list of lists, where each inner list is a copy of box but with some entries modified?  It would be helpful if you include a small example input and the expected output.

Comment: i wrote out an example myself using setup `current_boxes = [[1], [2], [3, 5]]; s = 1.1; all_boxes = []` but i agree its tricky to get list comp right in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using list comprehension you're building a new list. You don't need to use append.

You don't need to use an interator with list indices and range either.

The inner loop would look like this :

```
[value*s for value in box]
```

Here we're building a new list which be the original list with each item multiplied by your `s` variable.

Now, we need to create a such list for each box in your `current_boxes`.

The outer loop that would do this may be like :

```
[box for box in current_boxes]
```

When combined :

```
all_boxes = [[value*s for value in box] for box in current_boxes]
```

Comment: nice, look like OP just needed to switch order of `for` statements. good catch.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
all_boxes =[list(map(lambda y : y*s, box)) for box in current_boxes]
```

We are using the build in python map() function,
it takes in as first argument a function that is applied to each element of the second iterable argument (a list in our case ).
the map() returns a iterable so we cast it to 'list' for obtaining the desidered result.

this 'lambda y : y*s' function can be also expressed in this way:

```
def mult_by_s(element):
    element*s

all_boxes =[list(map(mult_by_s, box)) for box in current_boxes]
```

but it requires that 's' is global so lambda y : y*s is a better fit in my opinion.

Also another approach is to use only map function to resolve the problem

```
 all_boxes =list(map(lambda box :list(map(lambda y : y*s, box)), current_boxes))
```

Comment: While this werks, the mixing of styles is a bit odd, and I'm not sure what it gains over nested list comprehensions.

Comment: It' just a differt paradigm to solve the problem, also I dont think  is the case for python but the map operatin can be parallelized potecially improoving performance, in fact the map/reduce operation are very common for large scale data manipolation in framework like Spark or hadoop-MapReduce